# Importing Neo4J data into Gephi

Tags: graph, neo4j, graph-databases, gephi

Beginner in Neo4J so excuse my stupid and silly questions.

I need to visualize my Graph database created using Neo4J into Gephi. I need this so that I can visualize my entire graph.

Using the inbuilt viewer of Neo4J I get many restrictions and as such I don't wish to use it to view my dataset.

Kindly guide as to how Neo4J graph database can be imported in Gephi.

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be to export your database in `graphml` format using [Neo4j-shell-tools](https://github.com/jexp/neo4j-shell-tools#graphml-export). You can then import a graphml graph in Gephi.

Since the database could be large, I suggest you export different subgraphs (only a subset of the properties or edge types) of your Neo4j database.

Answer (score 0):

I used to stream data from Neo4j to Gephi thanks to the [APOC](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/index32.html#_streaming_data_to_gephi) procedure. This is a good solution to not loose data.